# MongoDB - Not able to get the error message and return as response

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My Collection.save() function is working fine and identifying duplicate key values. But, when duplicate values occur , I am not able to get the entire error message as response.

My User.save function

```
const user = new User({
          first_name,
          last_name,
          email,
          username,
          password: cryptedPassword,
          bYear,
          bDay,
          bMonth,
          gender,
        }).save(function (err, data) {
          if (data) {
            console.log("inside save then data");
            return res.status(200).send(data);
          } else {
            console.log("inside save then err");
            return res.status(200).send(err);
          }
        });
```

My console message

(if I remove the else part

[image]

But when I try to send the err message as response json, I get only the below response in my postman

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "email": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "email": "sab1@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

How to get the full error message, so that i can intimate the duplicate key issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/error.html), when an error is throw, you can check for the `msg` property.

Below is a full example

```
const user = new User({
          first_name,
          last_name,
          email,
          username,
          password: cryptedPassword,
          bYear,
          bDay,
          bMonth,
          gender,
        })

return user.save(function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("inside save then err");
            return res.status(500).send(err.msg);
        });

            console.log("inside save then data");
            return res.status(200).send(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using async/await. In catch, you can check if the error is a duplicate key error or not, and you can create custom error messages. Also, return statusCode 400 instead of 200.

```
const user = new User({
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
  username,
  password: cryptedPassword,
  bYear,
  bDay,
  bMonth,
  gender,
});

try {
  await user.save();
} catch (err) {
  if (err.code === 11000) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: although the answer is valid in another context, it's not related to the question the user made. He not ask for any kind of concerns, he wants to know how show the error message of mongo error object.